# Difference between \015 & \012 and \r & \n

Tags: c#, .net, c++, encoding

I have an old C++ program that is writing files and FTPing them to a IBM mainframe.

This program is being converted to C#.

Things seems OK in transferring but the mainframe viewer is not displaying the file properly.

What is the difference between `\015` & `\012` and `\r` & `\n`?  C++ is using the numbers and C# is using `\r\n`.

Could this be why things don't appear properly?

The files are getting transferred as ASCII so unsure why it appears like garbage!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\015` is an octal literal, which C# does not support.
C# parses it as `\0` (character code zero) followed by the two characters `15`

Answer (score 7):

There is no difference between `\r\n` and `\015\012`.

In C(++), the `\0XX` escape sequence denotes a literal octal representation of a char. If you print these values as numbers, you should see that `\r` equates to `13` and `\n` equates to `10`.

Octal is base 8, and when converted to base 10, `015` equates to `13`, and `012` equates to `10`. I hope that clears things up.

Comment: There is a difference on the mainframe end though, which might explain the original source using explicit numbers.

Comment: Would the IBM Mainframe not interpret \r \n hence the garbarge loooking file?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's somewhat logical. Modern day standards are well, modern, so it would stand to reason that an old application wasn't privy to such things as \r\n (cross-compiling, maybe?), and thus had to use literals.